# Xcode out of sync with filesystem

Tags: xcode

I did changes in my project and committed everything. Lets say "**Commit1**". Then I started doing some more changes in Xcode.

But then I did `git reset hard master.`

After this, Xcode does not show new files that were committed in "**Commit1**".

But all the changes are present in filesystem.

What do I need to do to see my **Commit1** new fiiles back in Xcode??

I even tries checking out the project again. But the changes are still not shown in Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried closing Xcode and reopening it?

Comment: I did try closing and re-opening. Right now, I just manually added back all missing files. But I am not sure what did I miss when adding back :(